# How to save all images in a separate folder?

Tags: r

So, I am running the following code:

```
dirtyFolder = "Myfolder/test"
filenames = list.files(dirtyFolder, pattern="*.png")
for (f in filenames)
{
    print(f)
    imgX = readPNG(file.path(dirtyFolder, f))
    x = data.table(img2vec(imgX), kmeansThreshold(imgX))
    setnames(x, c("raw", "thresholded"))
    yHat = predict(gbm.mod, newdata=x, n.trees = best.iter)
    img = matrix(yHat, nrow(imgX), ncol(imgX))
    img.dt=data.table(melt(img))
    names.dt<-names(img.dt)
    setnames(img.dt,names.dt[1],"X1")
    setnames(img.dt,names.dt[2],"X2")
    Numfile = gsub(".png", "", f, fixed=TRUE)
    img.dt[,id:=paste(Numfile,X1,X2,sep="_")]
    write.table(img.dt[,c("id","value"),with=FALSE], file = "submission.csv", sep = ",", col.names = (f == filenames[1]),row.names = FALSE,quote = FALSE,append=(f != filenames[1]))

    # show a sample
    if (f == "4.png")
    {
        writePNG(imgX, "train_101.png")
        writePNG(img, "train_cleaned_101.png")
    }
}
```

What it does is basically, takes as input images which have noise in them and removes noise from them. This is only the later part of the code which applies the algorithm prepared from a training dataset (not shown here).

Now, I am not able to figure out, how can I save the cleaned image for each of the images in the `test` folder. That is, I wish to save the cleaned image for each of the images in the folder and not just the `4.png` image. The output image should have the name as `4_cleaned.png` if the input image has the name `4.png` and it should be saved in a separate folder in the same directory. That is, if input image has the name `x.png`, the output image should have the name `x_cleaned.png` and saved in a separate folder. How can I do it?

Tldr; I just want to save the variable named `img` for each of the filename as `number_cleaned.png` where `number` corresponds to the original file name. These new files should be saved in a separate folder.

Comment: I’m not really sure what your question is, since the code contains a lot of irrelevant detail and the text isn’t very clear. What prevents you from putting the folder name into the filename when saving the file?

Comment: @KonradRudoplh, read the `Tldr` version, and let me know if you understand it now.

Comment: @Rob what do you mean with the 'separate folder'?

Answer (score 1):

> Tldr; I just want to save the variable named img for each of the filename as number_cleaned.png where number corresponds to the original file name. These new files should be saved in a separate folder.

Alright, so construct the output filename using [`file.path`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/file.path.html) and a function such as `paste` or `sprintf`:

```
folder_name = 'test'
output_filename_pattern = file.path(folder_name, '%s_cleaned.png')

remove_extension = function (filename)
    gsub('\\.[^.]$', '', filename)

for (f in filenames) {
    # … your code her …

    new_filename = sprintf(output_filename_pattern, remove_extension(f))
    # … save file here …
}
```

Comment: how do I exactly write the image? Will it be something like, `writePNG(img,new_filename)`?

Comment: Basically, in the original code that I posted, whatever I am doing for a single image, that is, `4.png`, I wish to do that for every image given as input.